# To get Selected the Checkbox value of listview in WPF

Tags: wpf, checkbox, selected

I am having the code like

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Height="110.277" Margin="4,0,3,-138" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>

        <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="100" />-->
        <!--<CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"  Width="100"/>-->
        <CheckBox Name="chk1" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsPersonChecked}" Checked="checked_accname"   Width="100" />

      </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

In which I will bind the value for checkbox dynamically from db at buttonclick event I can't able to get the value of checked checkbox of listview.

Please help me regarding this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is the problem? your code should work

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to get the checked value from the UI. Use the IsPersonChecked property from the data object.

```
var persons = listView1.DataContext as Persons;
var selectedPersonsQuery = from person in persons
                           where person.IsPersonChecked
                           select person;
```

**EDIT**

After understanding that you used a DataView your query would be something like this:

```
var dataView = listView1.DataContext as DataView;
var selectedPersonRowsQuery = from row in dataView
                              where row["IsPersonChecked"]
                              select row;
```

Comment: Hi you have mentioned Persons in listview1.DataContext as Persons (what is Persons),i am viewing error on Persons

Comment: @karthik2004k - Persons is the collection of objects that is bound to   to the listbox.

Comment: hi i have binded the value for checkbox dynamically in windowload event as  DataSet dss = dal.get_user();
            listView1.ItemsSource = dss.Tables[0].DefaultView; so how can i get the checked checkbox values at runtime in this scenarios

Comment: @karthik2004k - I added to my answer. Again, do not try to get the state of the checkboxes but read the value of the column.